# Problems implementing HTTPS Rest API on a Unity project

Tags: android, api, rest, unity-game-engine, https

I'm working on a customer’s  Android app that requires to host a REST API on it. Basically there are some Android devices that receive requests from some system (that belongs to our customer) and act accordingly to that information. (I know this behavior is weird, but that's the way it was requested). 
It's already done, the only problem is that it must listen on HTTPS. We generated a self-signed certificate and associated it with the Unity project,  but for some reason the requests don't arrive. On HTTP it works fine.

I don't know if it has something to do with Unity blocking HTTPS, but we have looked for a solution a long time with no results.

Here is a screenshot of a failed test using postman to simulate our customer’s system sending requests:
[Failed https test with postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoHU8.png)
Any ideas on how to implement this? 
Thanks